# rdlc-repeat data in report header across multiple pages

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am using ssrs 2012.

How can I repeat username in the report header? ReportItem doesn't work if the report spans across more than one page.
I was told to use Internal parameters but there is no such option with rdlc.
Can this somehow be done in codebehind?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confusing about your problem.

Just add a page header, rigth click on report design surface, insert->page header:

[image]

Add a text box and set the expression value to the following built-in field

[image]

You should get something like this in every page:

[image]
[image]

Note I am using rdl but built-in fields is available for both RDL and RDLC.

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that if the report spans over multiple pages  then the value disappears. I get the data from the database.